# JNI Newbyte array is taking a lot of time to execute

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a simple JNI call in which new bytes are allocated. I made a call to NewByteArray() function. But that function is taking around 30 seconds to allocate memory. How to make it fast or is I am missing something. sdk used is Android API level 21 (Android L)

```
    static jobject getImageRGBABuffer(JNIEnv *env,ASUns8 *buffer, int width, int height)
    {

        /*some code*/
        //size os around 300000
        jbyteArray rgbByteArray = env->NewByteArray(size);
        //The above statement is taking around 30 seconds. 
        //How to make it fast or is I am missing something
        return byteBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: 30 *seconds*?  It should take a few microseconds, unless a GC is in progress, in which case it should still take only a small number of microseconds.  Something is very wrong if you can measure the time to allocate 300K with a stopwatch.

Comment: How much time does it take if you allocate it in Java with `new byte[]` and pass it to your JNI function as an argument?